# Why is used CheckForNull and NotNull at the same time?

Tags: java, null, findbugs

I saw this code. And I am wondering why these two annotations are used at the same time? *CheckForNull* is from code analysis tool and check compile time that the **property can be null**. But NotNull is runtime check and said that the property is **NOT** null? Why they are used at the same time?Are they in conflict one another?

```
import javax.annotation.CheckForNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    @CheckForNull
    @NotNull
    private Info Info;
```

**JSR-303**

Used for **runtime** bean validation, NOT static code analysis

javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

javax.validation.constraints.Null

**Findbugs**

Used by the Findbugs static code analysis tool

edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.Nonnull

edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.CheckForNull

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? They're used by different tools at different times.

Comment: But one checks if the property is null, and the other that the property is Not null? How is this possible I don not understand completely .

Comment: Ah, no, I'm with you now. Yes, it looks like the CheckForNull should be Nonnull. Having both styles of annotation make sense, but these two are contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a bit strange.

I suspect it is simply a mistake; e.g.

- it is carelessness,
- it is an artifact of switching from static to dynamic checking, or vice versa, without doing the job completely,
- it is a result of accepting an IDE's suggested corrections (imports) without thinking, or
- someone who doesn't understand what the annotations really mean.

---

If you really want to know, then "deep dive" the version control history and/or ask the author.

Comment: It is not in a single class it is on production code on 10 or more places... Ok I will ask people around.